Flutter: How to resolve "Bottom Overflowed" error in my layout? (Slivers)
I'm developing a Flutter application and encountering a "bottom overflowed" error. I know there are many similar questions, but none have helped in my case. Here's my code:

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('title'),
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
                    child: DepotInventarSliderFlex(),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15.0,
                      vertical: 10.0,
                    ),
                    child: const Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 23.0,
                            ),
                            'some text',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                          ),
                          'some text',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  TabBar(
                    controller: tabController,
                    tabs: const [
                      Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                      Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                      Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _StickyTabBarDelegate(
                child: const CartFloatingButton(),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                children: [
                  _getTabContentAt(0),
                  _getTabContentAt(1),
                  _getTabContentAt(2),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget _getTabContentAt(int index) {
    List<Widget> tabContents = [
      Column(
        children: [
          ExpandableButtonList(
            buttons: testData,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          ExpandableButtonList(
            buttons: testData,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(child: Text('...')),
      ),
    ];
    return tabContents[index];
  }
}

  class _ExpandableButtonListState extends State<ExpandableButtonList> {
  int _selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          // height: double.infinity,
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
            runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
            spacing: 8.0,
            children: [
              for (var i = 0; i < widget.buttons.length; i++)
                TerminalTapBarButton(
                  label: widget.buttons[i].label,
                  isSelected: _selectedIndex == i,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = _selectedIndex == i ? -1 : i;
                    });
                  },
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        if (_selectedIndex != -1)
          Items(items: widget.buttons[_selectedIndex].items),
      ],
    );
  }
}

I get the 'bottom overflowed' error when I open TabBarView() content that is a bit longer.
I tried wrapping the ExpandableButtonList() with Flexible and Expanded, but I still have the error.
SingleChildScrollView() doesn't help because I need the entire page content to scroll together, not the tab content separately.
How can I resolve this overflow issue while maintaining my current layout structure?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here are some pictures; I hope they will be helpful.
Before click on content:

After click on content:

SOLUTION:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Title'),
    centerTitle: false,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  ),
  body: Builder(builder: (context) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15.0,
                vertical: 10.0,
              ),
              child: const Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Some text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 23.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Some text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle:
                NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: CartFloatingButtonDelegate(
                child: const CartFloatingButton(),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: [
          _getTabContentAt(0),
          _getTabContentAt(1),
          _getTabContentAt(2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }),
);

}

Can you share an image of where this overflow is happening?

@ValentinVignal I've added two pictures; I hope they will be helpful.

Based on your provided code snippet, you can resolve the issue of "bottom overflowed" by switching from CustomScrollView to NestedScrollView. This change allows you to maintain a scrollable page where all content scrolls together seamlessly, including the TabBarView contents.
I've tested this locally, and here's the complete code based on your layout requirements. This code should work for your needs. Here is the image as well:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _StickyTabBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget child;

  _StickyTabBarDelegate({required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return child;
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 56.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 56.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant _StickyTabBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('title'),
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: const Divider(
                  thickness: 0.5,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 15.0,
                    vertical: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Some text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 23.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Some text',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: TabBar(
                  controller: tabController,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },

          body: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              _getTabContentAt(0),
              _getTabContentAt(1),
              _getTabContentAt(2),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget _getTabContentAt(int index) {
    List<Widget> tabContents = [
      ExpandableButtonList(
        buttons: testData,
      ),
      Column(
        children: [
          ExpandableButtonList(
            buttons: testData,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(child: Text('...')),
      ),
    ];
    return tabContents[index];
  }
}

class ExpandableButtonList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<TestData> buttons;

  ExpandableButtonList({required this.buttons});

  @override
  _ExpandableButtonListState createState() => _ExpandableButtonListState();
}

class _ExpandableButtonListState extends State<ExpandableButtonList> {
  int _selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Wrap(
            alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
            spacing: 8.0,
            children: List.generate(
              widget.buttons.length,
              (index) => TerminalTapBarButton(
                label: widget.buttons[index].label,
                isSelected: _selectedIndex == index,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = _selectedIndex == index ? -1 : index;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (_selectedIndex != -1) Expanded(child: Items(items: widget.buttons[_selectedIndex].items)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TestData {
  final String label;
  final List<String> items;

  TestData({required this.label, required this.items});
}

List<TestData> testData = [
  TestData(label: 'Button 1', items: List.generate(50, (index) => 'Item ${index + 1}')),
  TestData(label: 'Button 2', items: ['Item 3', 'Item 4']),
  TestData(label: 'Button 3', items: ['Item 5', 'Item 6']),
];

class TerminalTapBarButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final bool isSelected;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  TerminalTapBarButton({required this.label, required this.isSelected, required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
      ),
      child: Text(label),
    );
  }
}


class Items extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> items;

  Items({required this.items});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: items.map((item) => Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(item),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
              )
            ],
          )).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


What Did I Change:

NestedScrollView: I replaced CustomScrollView with NestedScrollView in the body of the Scaffold. This lets the entire page scroll together while managing nested scrolling effectively.
SingleChildScrollView in Tab Content: I wrapped the content in TabBarView (inside the _getTabContentAt method) with SingleChildScrollView to ensure that each tab's content can scroll independently when needed.
Adjustments in _ExpandableButtonListState: I made sure _ExpandableButtonListState manages its state correctly and wraps content appropriately for scrolling.


Thank you very much for your help. Your code structure helped me a lot. I just added a few missing elements.
